# How can I add the BigQuery admin role to the Cloud Deployment Manager Jinja file?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-deployment-manager

I use Cloud Deployment Manager to create datasets and tables. I need to give `bigquery.admin` role to service account. I have already give OWNER access role but it is not enough to process. Is it possible to give BigQuery admin role with  using Cloud Deployment Manager?

```
resources:
- name: big-query-dataset
  type: bigquery.v2.dataset
  properties:
    datasetReference:
      datasetId: id
    location: US
    access:
    - role: OWNER
      "userByEmail": "{{ SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}"
```

Comment: If you use this `role: admin` do you get an error?

Comment: I tried with `role: admin` . Deployment returned error message: "Invalid or missing role"

Comment: Per this link, https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference, you should use this `bigquery.admin`

Comment: Role can be OWNER, WRITER or READER according to this link https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets.  I wonder if there's any way to give Bigquery Admin role.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#roles) you got the role bigquery.admin

Based on the sample of code provided, it should look like this:

```
 - role: roles/bigquery.admin
      "userByEmail": "{{ SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}"
```

However, take a look at this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/set-access-control-resources#setting_an_iam_policy_in_your_configuration) which explains how to set an IAM policy in your configuration with Deployment Manager.

Hope this helps.